# Maintain the value across two jsp pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have to take the value in a table:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">    
    var activeRequest;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".i_search").on("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            activeRequest = $(this).closest('tr').find('.request').text();
            renderElement();        
        });     
    });

    function renderElement(inUrl){
        $.ajax({
            url:  "/?pagename=SiteEntry_LT_EM/Advise/CS_Advise_Detail",
            type: "POST",
            data : {"advice_id":activeRequest}
        })     
        .done(function( response ) {
            $("#popUpDetail").html(response).fadeIn('slow');  
        });     
    }   
</script>
```

In the other jsp page I have:

```
<%= ics.GetVar("advice_id") %>
```

But when I clicked `$(".i_search")` the value `ics.GetVar("advice_id")` in the other page don't change. Maybe this value is save in the cache.

I did the same using PHP and it works, every time I cliked the data change. Now I'm even more confused.

In PHP:

```
<?php echo $_POST["advice_id"]; ?>
```

Comment: Pages already served don't get updated unless they're doing ajax polling or something like that.

Comment: Even if I'm calling again with the 'onclick' event?

Comment: Any idea? @developerwjk

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant you wanted this ajax call to update a different tab. You should change your title because its misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when using POST, you should not include the parameters in the url but in the data section. Don't mix and do it both ways.

Second, if you suspect a caching issue, in your ajax call, include a random parameter and/or set cache: false, like this:

```
   $.ajax({
        url:  "/",
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data : 
        {
          "advice_id":activeRequest, 
           "pagename": "SiteEntry_LT_EM/Advise/CS_Advise_Detail"
          "r": Math.random() 
        }
    })
```

You can also set no-cache headers in the servlet or jsp that is being called by the ajax to prevent the browser from caching it:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```

Comment: Thanks, it was a paremeter in the Oracle Web Center Sites at the SiteEntry:  `SiteEntry_LT_EM/Advise/CS_Advise_Detail` Caching rules: Deleted cache.